# Connecting methods to buttons and initializing

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, addressbook

I recently started learning Swift and for my first app (Master-Detail Template), I am trying to pull data (add contacts to a list) from my Address Book. I am trying to connect my *showAddressBook* method to the + button in the Master. The build fails on the init line (error: "Initializers may only be declared within a type"), so I'm guessing my code is wrong.

```
func showAddressBook() {
    var addressBookController = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.alloc()
    init(addressBookController = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController) {
        self.addressBookController = presentViewController(presentViewController: addressBookController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I can upload the code for connecting Address Book data if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't the way you init the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
simply write :

```
    func showAddressBook() {

    var addBook = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    self.presentViewController(addBook, animated: true) { () -> Void in}
}
```

or you can use another initialiser 
and then use the presentViewController.
note : using the same name for two variables (addressBookController) is bad programming habit :D

Comment: So I replaced the 3 lines in the func to what you wrote and the app continued to crash. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, it's still throwing an error, perhaps there is something wrong with my other code. error msg below

Comment: 2014-12-29 20:46:01.663 Networker[3999:1463978] -[Networker.MasterViewController showAddressBook:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155864a0
2014-12-29 20:46:01.666 Networker[3999:1463978] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Networker.MasterViewController showAddressBook:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155864a0'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x2464a49f 0x31e40c8b 0x2464f8b9 0x2464d7d7 0x2457f058 0x27b3d9fb 0x27ca149d 0x27b3d9fb 0x27b3d9a1 0x27b28613 0x27b3d40d 0x27b3d0e7 0x27b369b1 0x27b0d15d 0x27d80ab9 0x27b0bbb9 0x24610d57 0x24610167 0x2460e7cd 0x2455c3c1 0x2455c1d3 0x2b95a0a9 0x27b6bfa1 0xf8614 0xf8650 0x323c0aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: oooh if you connecting this function to a button you should write it like this   @IBAction func showAddressBook(sender: AnyObject) 
and then connect it to the button (programmatically or by ctrl drag)

Comment: ahhh makes sense. The one issue is that the button doesn't seem to be visible via main.storyboard